# Integration of Unity and Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, unity-game-engine, integration

I need a little bit of help with integration of Unity into Eclipse.

My reference page is this =>  [here](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/71607-Integrating-Unity-and-Eclipse)

I have Unity3D Pro version and Android Plugin Pro Version

- Set up your Unity Android project as you would normally and hit
  Build.
- Enter your project folder, go to Temp/StagingArea.
- Copy all project files to a new folder.
- Import this folder as a new Android project in Eclipse.
- Mark this project as a library in the properties window for the
  project. (Right click on the project name, go to Properties->Android
  and mark "Is Library".)
- Create a new Android project in Eclipse. This will constitute the
  Java part of your project.
- Add the Unity Android project as a library to your new project.
  (Right click on the project name, go to Properties->Android, select
  "Add...", add the project.)
- Add the classes.jar library to the Library references for your new
  project. (In properties, go to Java_Build_path->Libraries, select
  "Add External Jar...", navigate to
  UNITY_INSTALLATION\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\and roidplayer\bin and
  add classes.jar)

By now, If I am running this little project into my device I get something like this

You can see the picture from this link.

https://copy.com/vVaCyQTEUECV

The next Step is this:

- Move the assets folder from the library project to the new project.
  (Android does not allow assets to be utilized in libraries, and this
  last step has to be repeated whenever the Unity project is rebuilt.)

I am moving the asset folder and the res folder from the library project to the new project.

After that I am moving the AndroidMnifest.xml from the library and replacing in the project

This is my Code from MainActivity.java

```
package com.Developer.PackMan;

import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity;


import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends UnityPlayerNativeActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        
}
}
```

And this is Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.Developer.PackMan" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:versionName="1.0" android:versionCode="1" android:installLocation="preferExternal">
  <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
  <application android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="false">
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="false" />
    </activity>
  </application>
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
  <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" />
</manifest>
```

After I am building it i got an error with the following text

The application )process com.Developer.Packman) has stopped  unexpectedly please try again.

The problem is that I am not getting any kind of Errors in LogCat or Console, everything is clear.

I really need your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For an app which has to show both Unity3d and regular Android UI, I wrote a guide for my future use. AFAIR it's based on Unity3d version 4.3. I hope it's detailed enough :)

Based on links:
http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/98315-Using-Unity-Android-In-a-Sub-View/page4?p=1477830&viewfull=1#post1477830

https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/dev-guide/extending-unity-android-activity-and-adding-custom-views-eclipse

**Pre-setup:**

In order to start integrating Unity3d and Android you need the classes.jar file found in '...Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\androidplayer\bin'. You can place it in your workspace directory.

**Setup:**

1. Start with an Android project which will contain all the Android
   bits.
2. Prepare the Unity3d Android project. Import the Unity project
   into your workspace like a regular Android project.
3. RMB on the Unity project, click “Properties”, then go to “Android” and tick the “Is
   Library?” check box.
4. RMB on the Android project, click “Properties”, then go to “Android” and click “Add” to add a library - the Unity project - to the Android one.
5. Still in the “Properties” dialog, go to “Java Build Path” and select the “Libraries” tab.
   There, click “Add external JAR” and navigate to the classes.jar
   file.
6. Ensure both projects target the same SDK.
7. Move the “assets” folder from the Unity project into the Android project. This step
   has to be repeated each time your Unity project is rebuilt.

**Coding:**

This guide assumes your goal is to have an Android activity which will display both a Unity model and regular Android UI.

1. Add the following line to the base of the project’s manifest file: ‘’.
2. Add the following line in the manifest to the activity which is supposed to contain the Unity model: ‘’. This enables touch events to be passed to both Unity models and regular Android UI.
3. Make the activity extend UnityPlayerActivity rather than Activity.
4. Don’t add the ‘setContentView’ straight in onCreate() - this leads to unwanted behaviour - in my case the Unity model was very small and couldn’t be interacted with; instead, in onResume() find the parent view of the UnityPlayer object and in it inflate the layout and add all the other UI elements. Note that it’s possible that finding of said view might need to be done in a separate thread.

**Troubleshooting:**

- NoClassDefFoundException (or similar) on classes which extend UnityPlayerActivity:  go to Properties of your Android project, then Java Build Path -> Order and Export and tick classes.jar (in my case it was at the top of the list if that makes any difference). Press OK, clean the project, try to run again and PRAY…
- multiple dex files define Lcom/unity3d/player/nativeloader - make sure the “libs” dir in the Unity project does NOT contain the “unity-classes.jar” file.
- (Not sure but worth a try) problems in the src folder - remove the contents of the src folder

Here's some sample code to illustrate the `Activity` which holds the Unity3d object:

```
private Button buttonChangeColour;
private UnityPlayer unityPlayer = null;

@Override
public void onResume() {

    super.onResume();

    if (unityPlayer == null) {

        View rootView = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        unityPlayer = findUnityPlayerView(rootView);

        if (unityPlayer != null) {

            ViewGroup unityPlayerParentView = (ViewGroup)(unityPlayer.getParent());
            View mainHomeView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_home, null);
            LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            unityPlayerParentView.addView(mainHomeView, layoutParams);

            buttonChangeColour = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonChangeColour);
            buttonChangeColour.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // [...]
                }
            });
        }
    }
}

private UnityPlayer findUnityPlayerView(View view) {

    if (view instanceof UnityPlayer) {

        return (UnityPlayer) view;
    }
    if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {

        ViewGroup childrenViews = (ViewGroup) view;

        for (int i = 0; i < childrenViews.getChildCount(); i++) {

            UnityPlayer foundView = findUnityPlayerView(childrenViews.getChildAt(i));

            if (foundView != null) {

                return foundView;
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: (For Unity 4.5): Have you tried using the [export] "Google Android Project" option in the build settings dialog in Unity? That creates a Android project. My approach would be to merge the generated project into my Android project, by taking all relevant files from the project that Unity generated, but using my own java files (which would be like the ones in the unity-generated project, but with my own additional code), my manifest etc. Then I'd build with gradle. Any reason why that wouldn't work?

Answer (score 1):

which Unity version are you using? if 4.X i have wrote a tutorial about eclipse integration [here](http://nevzatarman.wordpress.com/2014/04/04/unity-android-plugin-tutorial-series-part4-unity3d-google-play-game-services/)

also you can check my previous tutorials, I explain how to write a plugin without using eclipse.